# Ubuntu won't start with charger plugged in

Tags: boot, usb

Im running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on an usb stick. It starts when im not charging the computer but if i have my charger connected while powering on my laptop it wont start. Im using a lenovo thinkbook 14 g2 itl.